# Можете объяснить или написать, в чем моя ошибка? Мой учитель сказал, что я должен создать 3 функции, я пытался, но не понял

Tags: python, массивы, функции, list, length

я написал этот код и отправил своему учителю, но после этого я получил ответ:

Результаты верны, но выполните задание:
Разложите задачу на подзадачи, создайте функцию для каждой из них. В программе должно быть создано не менее 3 функций:

1. Входные данные
2. Расчет
3. Выходные данные

Я пытался создать некоторые функции, но это не работает.

```
M1 = []

M2 = []

M3 = []

m1_length = int(input("Enter M1's length:"))

for i in range(0, m1_length):

    num1 = str(input("Enter M1 elements: "))
    M1.append(num1)

m2_length = int(input("Enter M2's length:"))

for i in range(0, m2_length):

    num2 = str(input("Enter M2 elements: "))
    M2.append(num2)

def common_number(M1, M2):

    M1 = set(M1)
    M2 = set(M2)

    if (M1 & M2):
        print(M1 & M2)

M3.append(common_number(M1, M2))
```

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Ну, видимо, для ввода M1 и M2 нужно создать отдельную функцию. И для вывода M3 ещё одну функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну у вас же написано всё в задании:

> В программе должно быть создано не менее 3 функций:
>
> 1. Входные данные
> 2. Расчет
> 3. Выходные данные

Если я правильно понимаю:

1. В первую функцию вам нужно поместить код, который запрашивает **ввод пользователя**, эта функция должна возвращать результат этого ввода.
2. Вторая функция занимается **расчётом**, она у вас есть, только результат нужно не выводить на печать, а опять же возвращать.
3. Третья функция должна **выводить на печать** то, что посчитала вторая функция.
4. В основном коде вам нужно последовательно вызвать эти три функции, не забыть ещё **получить результат работы функции** там, где он есть, и **передать его следующей функции**.